# Object.values strips type information when key is number

Tags: typescript, object, method-chaining

I noticed that in TypeScript, `Object.values` does not seem to maintain type information about the values of the object you're getting, when the keys of the object are numbers.  For example:

```
interface PartyBag {
    toy: string;
    id: number;
    candy: 'snickers' | 'skittles'
}

interface AllTheBags {
    [key: number]: PartyBag
}

const bags: AllTheBags = {
    4: {
        toy: 'car',
        id: 4,
        candy: 'skittles'
    },
    // more items
}

// bagValues has type 'any'
const bagValues = Object.values(bags) 

// no type information for 'bag' variable
const carbags = Object.values(bags).filter(bag => bag.toy === 'car')
```

### [TS playground showing the issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApymAngITgc2QG8BYAKGUuTAHssAuZAZzClHwG5yrlgATRiACuAWwBG0LhSoI4IPg2QByJiGAIA1tCZLkAH2VMNwMGAA2EHeQC+5cqEixEKAIJmzAFQAWEPPibE3FQA2lqKwuLQALqM6Ji4BDZ2ZAg0ICzIYgRMjG6ePn4BALyB0pQArIykZTzUdIxKslBKADRBtbwCyOVtNTyy8ooqxqYWVjXWvTwAnFXttbRDfDTurfM8-IzTUx3IAwoNqupaUOM8tmQXyeQA8mIAVhAIYAB0AG5wZkKWABRZ-gBKF4wYBmRx-AjIIoAPkyBBeiyhRRKjQwSgByQA9JjKABafEEwlE4kk0lk8nk8jYvEUwnIADKAAkbgBVAAyABFkABRABKvJuvOQjL53OQOBZHmQHJu3PpADkPABCRi0olUnHINXanW6km3B5PV4fL6-f5MIEgsHQCGEGFw-AvEBpCAAD2ALHYYC87CRKKa6OuZCxmr1YfDFI1NO1yAA6oKANL0tAC1B8tkATTjAEkPIyGR5edn5QBxZAJ7kZ+mq7VRrURhuN3H2cDQeBIZDymhgPylHgQEQAB2wjDENBWEDkSWDZAcbecne7fhLUBoQkHfZCYUYLDYIHwMUXPcSl2SqXSYGQzsHEEYXeP+BXa43JWqPCU3vYSjmfSoA+HiisN88wXFcZB3I8zzvJ83xMD814QJaoLgv8UKwv8CI+vuALINS0CrnuhA+FAKBwAEbo3s8EB8C01BYDevAgDANBQCIcBgMAaTIGxDhwKA1EGpBxowb8CFIdaUC2mhDovP+2AAkAA)

I would expect that `bagValues` should automatically be casted to `PartyBag[]`, considering `AllTheBags` is clearly an object who's values are `PartyBag`s, and `Object.values` gives an array of the values of the object.  I could manually type it myself with `const bagValues: PartyBag[] = Object.values(bags)`, but when I want to chain methods from `Object.values(bags)` and stay succinct, the type information is lost in the methods that follow.  While I could still manually define the type with `.filter((bag: PartyBag) => bag.toy === 'car')`, but this opens up room for errors, as I could do this: `Object.values(notBags).filter(bag => bag.toy === 'car')`.  The type information is lost.  Note this *only happens when the object keys are a number*.  When the object keys are strings, the type information is maintained.

Is there a way to make sure that the return value of `Object.values(bags)` is `PartyBag[]`, which would then be passed to subsequent chained methods?

Comment: Reminder: an object being *assignable* to a type, doesn't mean it's constrained to *only* that type. Something that is a `AllTheBags` could also have other properties. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/WGk8kW). So, `Object.values` cannot *guarantee* that the only values you get are going to come from the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Records:

```
type AllTheBags = Record<number, PartyBag>;
```

Your solution doesn't work bescause in an interface, values can be of different types, even if you specify implicitly that any value is a `PartyBag`.
With a `Record`, you indicate explicitly to TypeScript that any value IS a `PartyBag`.

Comment: [There is functionally no difference](https://tsplay.dev/wgLv6N)

Comment: @VLAZ I'm not understanding your comment, or why this answer is downvoted.  Your ts playground uses this answer, and it seems to work as expected.  `Object.values(bags).filter(bag => ... )` correctly infers `bags` to be `PartyBag[]`, and `bag` to be a `PartyBag`.  (What *is* very strange about your playground is the line `const bags: AllTheBags = temp`, which one would expect to error?).  What exactly is the problem with this answer?

Comment: @SethLutske "*which one would expect to error?*" there is no error because [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) are only done when directly using an object literal as the assignment. Assigning another variable bypasses that. There are more ways around it but in general, that can be a very plausible scenario. When it happens, the code will fail *at runtime* while the compiler will be unaware of the potential problem. Just hit **Run** on the playground to see it.

Comment: So, I understand that part.  But the fact that excess property checks are not done when reassigning the variable is an interesting, but different problem, as far as I'm concerned.  I do understand your comment about `Object.values` not being able to guarantee that the only values of an item are the ones listed in the interface.  But, the `Record` solution at least gives some type information to the result of `Object.values`.  That's what I'm trying to do.  Lack of excess property checks has been a thorn in my side before, but it seems like a separate issue?

Comment: I agree with @SethLutske: it's a different problem. We can open an issue to TypeScript if it's not done.